# Scraping paginated results using python beautifulsoup 3

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pagination, export-to-csv

I am able to write code for First & last pages but only able to extract page 1 data in CSV. I need to extract All 10 pages data into CSV. Where in code i am going wrong?

Import the installed modules

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
```

To get the data from the web page we will use requests get() method

```
url = "https://www.lookup.pk/dynamic/search.aspx?searchtype=kl&k=gym&l=lahore"
page = requests.get(url)
```

To check the http response status code

```
print(page.status_code)
```

Now I have collected the data from the web page, let's see what we got

```
print(page.text)
```

The above data can be view in a pretty format by using beautifulsoup's prettify() method. For this we will create a bs4 object and use the prettify method

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())

outfile = open('gymlookup.csv','w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Name", "Address", "Phone"])
```

Find all DIVs that contain Companies information

```
product_name_list = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"CompanyInfo"})
```

To extract the first and last page numbers

```
paging = soup.find("div",{"class":"pg-full-width me-pagination"}).find("ul",{"class":"pagination"}).find_all("a")
start_page = paging[1].text
last_page = paging[len(paging)-2].text
```

Now loop through those elements

```
for element in product_name_list:
```

Takes 1 block of the "div",{"class":"CompanyInfo"} tag and finds/stores name, address, phone

```
name = element.find('h2').text
address = element.find('address').text.strip()
phone = element.find("ul",{"class":"submenu"}).text.strip()
```

writes the name, address, phone to csv

```
writer.writerow([name, address, phone])
```

now will go to the next "div",{"class":"CompanyInfo"} tag and repeats

```
outfile.close()
```

Comment: make sure your putting the code into one block (like you see in my solution). You can still add the bold parts, but just add them as # comments in your code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you were trying to do wrt. your code. As it currently is, it's difficult to read. Did you intend all of the headings to be code-comments? It would probably be easier to read this if you just re-copy your code into the question and format the whole code as a single code-block (select all the code and click on the `{}` icon above the textarea. Doing so will preserve the indentation that's critical in a Python program.

Comment: @Makyen I'll format the code in single block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just more loops you'll need. you'll need to loop through each page url now: see below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

root_url = "https://www.lookup.pk/dynamic/search.aspx?searchtype=kl&k=gym&l=lahore"
html = requests.get(root_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

paging = soup.find("div",{"class":"pg-full-width me-pagination"}).find("ul",{"class":"pagination"}).find_all("a")
start_page = paging[1].text
last_page = paging[len(paging)-2].text


outfile = open('gymlookup.csv','w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Name", "Address", "Phone"])


pages = list(range(1,int(last_page)+1))
for page in pages:
    url = 'https://www.lookup.pk/dynamic/search.aspx?searchtype=kl&k=gym&l=lahore&page=%s' %(page)
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

    #print(soup.prettify())
    print ('Processing page: %s' %(page))

    product_name_list = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"CompanyInfo"})
    for element in product_name_list:
        name = element.find('h2').text
        address = element.find('address').text.strip()
        phone = element.find("ul",{"class":"submenu"}).text.strip()

        writer.writerow([name, address, phone])

outfile.close()
print ('Done')
```

Comment: Wow, it really worked. And I really liked the page processing message. Once again, I was missing some loops. Thanks

Comment: I think it's good practice to insert those `print()` statements in there within loops, just as a way to test and debug for when things go wrong. After you get it working properly, it's simple to take those out. But like I said, nice to see where a script is in the entire process to check where/if it gets hung up somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should use page attribute as well like https://www.lookup.pk/dynamic/search.aspx?searchtype=kl&k=gym&l=lahore&**page=2**

Sample code for 10 pages:

```
url = "https://www.lookup.pk/dynamic/search.aspx?searchtype=kl&k=gym&l=lahore&page={}"
for page_num in range(1, 10):
   page = requests.get(url.format(page_num)
   #further processing
```